# PHP Regular Expression not matching

Tags: php, regex

I have a really simple PHP regular expression that isn't returning as a match, as seen below.

```
if(preg_match('[0-9]{3}','123')){
    echo "match";
}
else{
    echo "nope";
}
```

This should check if the string '123' matches the pattern '[0-9]{3}',  which of course it does - however it's not completing the true condition and is instead echoing "nope".

I've also tried:

```
if(preg_match('[0-9]{3}' '123') == '1'){
    echo "match";
}
else{
    echo "nope";
}
```

Any ideas? Do I need to configure my server or enable a regex property / library or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to add the [php delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

```
if(preg_match('~[0-9]{3}~','123')){
```

Comment: delimiters can anything ~ @ | ... for understanding

Comment: Recommend using `(...)` as delimiters. I do this for two reasons: 1) It subtly reminds me that index 0 of the matched set is the whole match, and 2) they come in matching pairs so you never, ever need to worry about escaping delimiters in the regex itself.

Comment: Probably best to use `/.../` since that's what most people, at least from the Unix world, expect to see as delimiters.

Comment: @AndyLester but it have some problems. I think you need to escape the forward slashes..

Comment: Ahh, none of the syntax listings I checked included this at first glance - thanks a lot everything is working as intended now.

Comment: You do not need to escape the slashes as delimiters.  You only need to escape a slash in the regex, and only if the delimiters are slashes.  For that reason, path and URL regexes can be annoying with slashes as delimiters (`/http:\/\//` vs. `{http://}`) but in most any other case, slashes are what people expect.

Comment: Also prefer `~` as delimiter :) Of course it depends on what you're mostly writing the patterns for. There are possibly more cases in general (paths, links,...) where one matches a `/` than matching literal `~`. @NiettheDarkAbsol 2.) For me such as `'~\(([^)]+)\)~'` is better readable than `'(\(([^\)]+)\))'` eg to capture parenthesized stuff to `$1`.